# How to configure Yesod to only listen on localhost?

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am using a minimal template and only found where to change port:

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = warp 3000 App
```

but I have no clue where to set anything else. In `App` there is some magic happening with routes generation, but no hint of any configuration.

According to `lsof -i` Yesod is listening on all interfaces which I don't want. I want to limit it only to loopback (127.0.0.1).

---

I came up with a workaround which can be used at a top of any handler (route) to check if client's IP matches:

```
onlyAllowedFromLocalhost :: Handler ()
onlyAllowedFromLocalhost = do
  let allowedIp = "127.0.0.1"
  host <- waiRequest <&> W.remoteHost <&> tshow
  unless (T.isPrefixOf (allowedIp <> ":") host) $
    sendResponseStatus forbidden403 ("Access is allowed only from " <> allowedIp)
```

For a proper solution see answer from [snak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64295727/9160022)

Comment: I think the standard way to go about this is to run Yesod/Warp behind a reverse proxy (Nginx or Apache), and let that worry about what to listen to.

Comment: @leftaroundabout It's not meant to run on a server, so adding another thing to configure is not really practical. Also it would not solve the issue, since yesod server would still be bound to all network interfaces, so it would still be be accessible from LAN (or even internet). (It would be better to solve this on a firewall, but I can't expect users to know how to set it up, so I prefer the application to be as safe as possible by default.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `warp` convenience method, you can convert your site to [`Application`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.18.4/docs/Yesod-Core.html#t:Application) using [`toWaiApp`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.6.18.4/docs/Yesod-Core-Dispatch.html#v:toWaiApp), then run it with [`runSettings`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.13/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:runSettings). Now, configure [`Settings`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.13/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#t:Settings) to bind only a loopback using [`setHost`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.3.13/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:setHost) and pass it to `runSettings`.

Comment: Thank you, this works nicely. I wish it was mentioned in the docs. Port can be set directly (even passed via env. variables), but host for some reason is not easy to change.